# Unable to give get_pages() more than one meta_key

Tags: wordpress

It appears that if the args you pass to get_pages( ) specifies more than one meta key, only the last one is considered.   I have the code below that specifies two meta keys:

[image]

Only 63 pages have a template of listing.php so without lines 107 and 108 I get 63 pages.  If I include 107 and 108 I get 234 pages, few of which have a template of listing.php.  So it looks like the function only takes the last meta specification in args. This  doesn't appear to be in the documentation.  Is there a way to require the pages to have a specific value in two meta keys?

Thanks

Comment: That array isn't valid. You can't have more than one key with the same name (`meta_key`). It will just use the last defined `meta_key` and `meta_value`. Where did you find that you can pass more than one meta key?

Comment: I didn't.  But it seems like you should be able to tell get_pages() to require a specific value in two or more meta keys, and the above seemed like the logical way to do it.  But, as you point out and I see now, you can't have the same key twice in any array, so it's the array that's causing the problem, not get_pages().  So, is there a way to have get_pages() require a specific value in two meta keys?

Comment: Check out my answer below. It looks like you can't with `get_pages` but there is another function `get_posts` which can do it.

Comment: BTW, you could try using `meta_query` for `get_posts` too. Maybe it will work and they just never documented it. Use it like I did in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That array that you have isn't valid. You can't use an array key more than one time. If an array key is duplicated, it will just overwrite the last one.

I did some searching online and found this post on the Wordpress SE: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40322/query-multiple-meta-key-values

It looks like it uses a `meta_query` tag to search for multiple keys. I checked the [documentation for `get_pages`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) but it unfortunately looks like it doesn't use `meta_query`. But it does link to a function named [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) that does use the [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts#Custom_Field_Parameters) tag. You can click on this link to see how this works: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts#Custom_Field_Parameters Notice how it uses an array of arrays to define each key-value pair. This way it doesn't repeat array keys.

You can use this function like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'listing.php',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'swept',
            'value' => 'no',
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'ASC'

);
$listings = get_posts($args);
```

Note that it uses "orderby" instead of "sort_column" and "order" instead of "sort_order"

Comment: Excellent!  I was able to do exactly what I wanted with get_posts().  Thank you!